# SoapClient ошибка [HTTP] Not Allowed

Tags: php, soap

Потаюсь отправить SOAP запрос на свой SOAP сервер из PHP:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);

$client = new SoapClient(
    'https://*.wsdl',
    [
        'location' => 'https://*.wsdl',
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    ]
);

class CheckTransactionArguments {
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $serviceId;
    public $transactionId;
    public $transactionTime;
}

$req = new CheckTransactionArguments();
$req->username = 'Test';
$req->password = 'asdasd';
$req->serviceId = 1;
$req->transactionId = 1;
$req->transactionTime = new DateTime();

$client->checkTransaction($req);
```

Скрипт падает, выдаёт 500. В логах всё лаконично "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Allowed in ..."

При этом $client->getFunctions() нормально отрабатывает и я получают список методов, где имеется метод checkTransaction.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: 500 ошибка - это проблема на сервере, проверьте логи и сообщите нам. HTTP Not Allowed (HTTP Code 405) отдается клиенту, если тип запроса не соответствует ожиданиям (GET вместо POST, к примеру)

Comment: Вот же написал в логи сыпется "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Allowed in ..."

Comment: * вы не написали специально, или это такой адрес? Добавьте сам WSDL по возможности.

Comment: Нет, адрес обычный, просто писать не стал. Файл, увы, добавить не могу, он конфиденциальный. Но там нет ничего особенного, разве что типы выделены в xsd файл.